# MVC 404 Error Page get called URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-error-pages

I write custom error pages for my MVC 5 web app. That's why I extended my *web.config*:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" >
  <error redirect="~/Error/?code=404" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

My `Index` action is called properly but I want to know the called url that was not found. How can I get it?

Comment: it should be in the query string

Comment: @SimonHalsey the `Request.QueryString` property contains only the query for the error page: `{code=404}`

Comment: @SimonHalsey The `Request.Url` property contains the path to my custom error page path: "https://localhost:44300/Error/?code=404"

Comment: HTTP is stateless. IIS is capturing the 404 and redirecting you. You'll need  to go about this in a different way. See [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026941/1944400)